# How to print function level calling graph by using Rose Compiler

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, compiler-construction

Hello I just installed [Rose Compiler](http://rosecompiler.org/) and by following the instructions on GitHub [here](https://github.com/rose-compiler/rose/wiki/Install-Using-apt-get)
I managed to install it successfully as well as execute it, now when I type `rajaChecker --version` it shows the version number which shows it is installed

for scanning the source code when I type command

```
rajaChecker test.cpp -report=report.txt
```

The command executes successfully and output generates which is useless for me as I want function level calling graph for the file or even project but the documentation is not clear about this, it would be the best if I can get the function level calling graph of the source code or preferably a project

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
bat-cg --help
```

From their
[github wiki page](https://github.com/rose-compiler/rose/wiki/ROSE-based-tools)

Then you might try

```
bat-cg test.cpp
```

Comment: command not foud, also tried with sudo but still got no luck . how to install this?

Comment: for your hint, I also tried to build from source still no luck, another thing, I searched the installed tools of rose compiler the output is very interesting it shows all tools are installed e.g. bat-cfg, bat-ana, bat-cc but only this specific command is not there bat-cg